# c# saving a text in a specific directory

Tags: c#

Here is my code;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string newFile =textBox1.Text;
    string temp = newFile.Replace("YNATEST.", "");
    SaveFileDialog a1 = new SaveFileDialog();
      a1.FileName = "";
      a1.Filter = "Text Files(*txt)|*.txt";
      a1.DefaultExt = "txt";
      a1.ShowDialog();
      StreamWriter yazmaislemi = new StreamWriter(a1.FileName);
      yazmaislemi.WriteLine(temp);
      yazmaislemi.Close();
}
```

it is saving the text on Desktop but i want to save it to the following path:

```
C:\Users\esra.ur\Desktop\projee1
```

Comment: Well then choose the directory in the dialog?

Comment: Just as an FYI, this code will write the file regardless if the user presses OK or Cancel. That being said, what directory are you choosing from the dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SaveFileDialog object has a property called InitialDirectory, which is a string you can specify, for example 

            `SaveFileDialog a1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            a1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\esra.ur\Desktop\projee1";`

If this directory doesn't exist, it will default back to documents. Be careful about writing a file even if the user tries to cancel. Hope this helps?
In response to your comment, it sounds like you want to hard code the destination file name. This is dangerous as you can get an exception if the directory doesn't exist, but you can use the following: (I'm not sure what you want to do with the file name)
'`string newFile = textBox1.Text;
            string temp = newFile.Replace("YNATEST.", "");
            StreamWriter yazmaislemi = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\esra.ur\Desktop\projee1\" + temp + ".txt");
            yazmaislemi.WriteLine(temp);
            yazmaislemi.Close();`

In this case you don't need the SaveFileDialog at all. I think this is what you're asking for, but it's dangerous to code in this way.

Comment: okey ,with this code its saving in projee1 but if i dont want to see the show dialog for saving. what should i do?

Answer (score 2):

1) Wrap your show dialog to check the result.

```
if(a1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
```

2) The SaveFileDialog has a property for setting an initial path. This is for the directory which will be shown when the dialog is first open. For the desktop you want to use the Environment.GetFolderPath like so.

```
a1.InitialDirectory =  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

3) Try to separate concerns:

```
private string OutputFile {get;set;}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.OutputPath))
    {
        SaveFileDialog a1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        a1.FileName = textBox1.Text;
        a1.Filter = "Text Files(*txt)|*.txt";
        a1.DefaultExt = "txt";
        a1.InitialDirectory =  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        if(a1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
          this.OutputFile = ai.FileName
        }
    }

    this.SaveFile(this.OutputFile);
}

private void SaveFile(string FileName)
{
    string newFile = FileName;
    string temp = newFile.Replace("YNATEST.", "");

    using(StreamWriter yazmaislemi = new StreamWriter(temp))
    {
        yazmaislemi.WriteLine(temp);
        yazmaislemi.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: with InitialDirectory i can save my text to the path but now i want it to save automaticly i mean without showing me the show dialog for saving. how can i do that?

Comment: It sounds like you want to be able to save the path? You could have a separate variable to hold the path. If the variable as not been set then show the open file dialog, otherwise just save.

Comment: I have updated my answer which should be closer to what I think you are looking for.

Comment: Also you should wrap the SreamWriter with a using statement. This is so it releases any file locks and resource locks which are applied when writting the file.

Answer (score 2):

use save file dialog, so you can save your text in your specific directory

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication30
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // When user clicks button, show the dialog.
    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
}

private void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Get file name.
    string name = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
    // Write to the file name selected.
    // ... You can write the text from a TextBox instead of a string literal.
    File.WriteAllText(name, "test");
}
}
}
```

this code snippets is from this link http://www.dotnetperls.com/savefiledialog

I hope it will help